# Create a specialized dictionary from a text file

Tags: python

I have a list of header files and values in a txt file I would like to read and in and write into a dictionary. Where the name is the key and the 0 or 1 is the value.

The format of the txt file looks like:

```
#define NAME 0
#define MOREOFTHESAME 1
```

the names are all different lengths but the values are all either 0 or 1.
I also want to strip the #define from each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict` here, `dict` expects a sequence with key value pairs. You can split the lines using `str.split` and pass the last two items using list slicing to `dict`.

```
with open('abc') as f:
    dic = dict(line.split()[1:] for line in f)

>>> print(dic)
{'NAME': '0', 'MOREOFTHESAME': '1'}
```

Example of `str.split`:

```
>>> strs = "#define MOREOFTHESAME 1"
>>> strs.split()
['#define', 'MOREOFTHESAME', '1']
>>> strs.split()[1:]
['MOREOFTHESAME', '1']
```

Using a dict-comprehension(works in py2.7+):

```
with open('abc') as f:
    dic = {k:v for k,v in (line.split()[1:] for line in f)}
...     
>>> dic
{'NAME': '0', 'MOREOFTHESAME': '1'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply split the line at each space, and ignore the 1st enrty:

```
with open('myFile.txt', 'rb') as fil:
    myDict = {}
    for line in fil:
        _, key, value = line.split()
        myDict[key] = value
```

Comment: why the binary read? Also `line.split()` should do it, not need to pass in `' '`

Comment: @1_CR You're right about the split. Opening the text file in "binary" mode actually doesn't make a difference for text files (as far as I can tell), but you can mess up binary files in windows if you forget the binary option. So, it's become a habit to always use 'rb' for both types of files, for both Windows and Linux.